# AngularJS controller does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

I just started learning mvc and thought angular is a good place to start with it. For the start i wanted only to see if i can set my controller to work. But im having issues.
To short my first post, here is the code:
index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js">
    </script>
    <title>afa</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stil-index.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="myapp">

    <div class="flex-container" ng-controller="mainController">
        <header>
            <h1>{{pages.name}} </h1>
        </header>

        <article class="article">
            <h1><?php echo "afgaga?" ?></h1>
            <p>
                <?php echo "agasdga" ?>
            </p>
            <p><strong><?php echo "agsadga" ?></strong>
            </p>
        </article>

        <footer>
            <?php $time=d ate(
            'l/d/m/y H:i:s');; echo $time;?> &nbsp &nbsp
            <?php echo "©";?>&nbsp &nbsp
            <?php echo
            "agadg"?>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('mainController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.pages = {
            name: 'glavna',
            key: 1
        };
    }
]);
```

I'v been trying to figure it out for quite some time, doing many variations but with no success :/ what is the problem here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Elaborate what is the problem?

Comment: You are using appname whereas you are initialising your module on app

Comment: in the second line of your "app.js" you have written  `appname.controller...` 
it should be `app.controller...`

Comment: I edited it, it was a posting mistake.
The problem is that i dont get the text from pages.name into my html. only this {{pages.name}}

Comment: Try initialising the script tag for your app.js above in head and check if the base url is correct for your script tags

Comment: What is the error you are getting in your console?

Comment: There is an extra space in `$time=d ate(`

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [Hello World! example](https://hello-angularjs.appspot.com/helloworld)

I guess that the right code is

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('mainController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
  $scope.pages = { 
    name: 'glavna' ,
    key: 1
  };
}]);
```

You are initializing your module as 'app', so you have to use this name later. Not 'appname'.

Comment: Yes, i just have edited it, i tried many things so it stayed like that, but it still doesnt work. I originally did write the code the way you just wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Change below code

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
appname.controller('mainController', ['$scope',
function($scope) {
$scope.pages = { 
name: 'glavna' ,
key: 1
};
}]);
```

with

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('mainController', ['$scope',
function($scope) {
$scope.pages = { 
name: 'glavna' ,
key: 1
};
}]);
```

This may help you

Answer (score 0):

Try including this line:

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

inside the head tag

Comment: I gave it a try and It stays the same.

Comment: @Čendi Put an alert or console in app.js and check if its executed

Answer (score 0):

It does work...

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('mainController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.pages = {
      name: 'glavna',
      key: 1
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js">
  </script>
  <title>afa</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stil-index.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="myapp">
  <div class="flex-container" ng-controller="mainController">
    <header>
      <h1>{{pages.name}} </h1>
    </header>

    <article class="article">
      <h1>
        <?php echo "afgaga?" ?>
      </h1>
      <p>
        <?php echo "agasdga" ?>
      </p>
      <p><strong><?php echo "agsadga" ?></strong>
      </p>
    </article>

    <footer>
      <?php $time=d ate(
            'l/d/m/y H:i:s');; echo $time;?> &nbsp &nbsp
      <?php echo "©";?>&nbsp &nbsp
      <?php echo
            "agadg"?>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It wont run on my local server. Okay, at least i know i did nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: no, its just keeps saying "{{pages.name"}}. I think i tried everything. I will now try to create another basic html page and try to run this again on it.

Comment: Thank you for trying it out and letting me know.

Comment: no prob:), further I suggest to remove your `php` code and try again in same snippet.

Comment: it was an old file that i just copied and used for this purpose. now i will create another one html exclusive :)

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js
```

with

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js
```

Comment: Did, but nothing changes.